# hibernate session.get does not load persistent object when migrate from hibernate 4.3.11 to 5.2.10 and use EntityManager insteadof SessionFactory

Tags: hibernate, jpa, entitymanager, hibernate-entitymanager

For a years in a project i used from hibernate **4.3.11.Final** and spring **4.3.1.RELEASE** to maniuplating and persisting objects. Newly i migrated to hibernate **5.2.10.Final** and encountered a problem that describe it. I have two domain class as you can see below:

```
public class Post extends BaseEntity<Long> {
    private String title;
    private Set<PostComment> comments = new HashSet<>(0);

    // getters and setters removed for brevity
}

public class PostComment extends BaseEntity<Long> {
    private Post post;
    private String descripton;

    // getters and setters removed for brevity
}

public abstract class BaseEntity<T> implements Serializable {
    private T id;
}
```

and these are hibernate mapping files:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="" table="tbl_post">
        <id name="id" type="long" >
            <column name="ID"  />
            <generator class="sequence" >
                <param name="sequence">RGH.SEQ_POST</param>
            </generator>
        </id>

        <property name="title" column="title" type="string" not-null="true" />

        <set name="comments" inverse="true" cascade="save-update,merge">
            <key>
                <column name="post_id" not-null="true" />
            </key>
            <one-to-many class="com.rgh.PostComment" />
        </set>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="" table="tbl_post_comment">
        <id name="id" type="long" >
            <column name="ID"  />
            <generator class="sequence" >
                <param name="sequence">RGH.SEQ_POST_COMMENT</param>
            </generator>
        </id>

        <property name="descripton" column="descripton" type="string" not-null="true" />

        <many-to-one name="post" column="post_id" entity-name="com.rgh.Post" not-null="true" />
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

In the `PostService` class exists two methods that one of theme persists `Post` entity and it's `PostComment`'s and another save the `Post` entity and logs count of it's `PostCommment`'s.

```
@Service
public class PostService {
    @Autowired
    private PostRepository repo;

    @Autowired
    private PostCommentRepository commentRepo;

    @Transactional
    public Long save() {
        Post post = new Post();
        post.setTitle("sample post");
        repo.save(post);

        Set<PostComment> postComments = new HashSet<>();
        for (int i = 0 ; i < 3 ; i++) {
            PostComment postComment = new PostComment();
            postComment.setPost(post);
            postComment.setDescription("description " + i);
            commentRepo.save(postComment);
        }

        return post.getId();
    }

    @Transactional
    public int saveAndGetDetailsCount(Post entity) {
        entity.setTitle(entity.getTitle() + " updated!");
        repo.save(entity);

        Post post = repo.loadById(entity.getId());
        System.out.println(post.Comments().size());
        return post.Comments().size();
    }
}
```

Both of `PostRepository` and `PostCommentRepository` are extended from `GenericRepository` that you can see it below:

```
@Repository
public class PostRepository extends GenericRepository<Post, Long> {
    @Override
    protected Class<Post> getDomainClass() {
        return Post.class;
    }
}

@Repository
public class PostCommentRepository extends GenericRepository<PostComment, Long> {
    @Override
    protected Class<PostComment> getDomainClass() {
        return PostComment.class;
    }
}

@Repository
public abstract class GenericRepository<T extends BaseEntity,PK extends Serializable> {

    protected Class<T> domainClass = getDomainClass();

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public Session getSession() {
        try {
            return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        return sessionFactory.openSession();
    }

    public PK save(T Entity) {
        Session session = getSession();
        if(entity.getId() == null) {
            session.save(entity);
        }
        else {
            entity = (T)session.merge(entity);
            session.update(entity);
        }
        return entity.getId();
    }

    public T loadByEntityId(PK entityId) {
        Session session = getSession();
        return  (T) session.get(domainClass.getName(), entityId);
    }
}
```

Everything is working fine when i call `save` method and then call `saveAndGetDetailsCount` it updates the entity and then executes `select...` query to load `Post` entity and then logs **3** and post comments.

But after i migrated to hibernate **5.2.10.Final** and applied these changes:

```
@Entity
@Table(schema = "RGH", name = "TBL_POST")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "sequence_db", sequenceName = "RGH.SEQ_POST", allocationSize = 1)
public class Post extends BaseEntity<Long> {

    @Column
    private String title;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "post", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @Cascade(value = { CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE, CascadeType.MERGE })
    private Set<PostComment> comments = new HashSet<>(0);

    // getters and setters removed for brevity
}

@Entity
@Table(schema = "RGH", name = "TBL_POST_COMMENT")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "sequence_db", sequenceName = "RGH.SEQ_POST_COMMENT", allocationSize = 1)
public class PostComment extends BaseEntity<Long> {

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "POST_ID", nullable = false)
    private Post post;

    @Column
    private String descripton;

    // getters and setters removed for brevity
}

public abstract class BaseEntity<T> implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "sequence_db")
    private T id;
}
```

and in then `GenericRepository` i used `EntityManager` to get `Session` class  as you can see below:

```
@Repository
public abstract class GenericRepository<T extends BaseEntity,PK extends Serializable> {

    protected Class<T> domainClass = getDomainClass();

    /* changed */
    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

    public Session getSession() {
        /* changed */
        return  em.unwrap(Session.class);
    }

    public PK save(T Entity) {
        Session session = getSession();
        if(entity.getId() == null) {
            session.save(entity);
        }
        else {
            entity = (T)session.merge(entity);
            session.update(entity);
        }
        return entity.getId();
    }

    public T loadByEntityId(PK entityId) {
        Session session = getSession();
        return  (T) session.get(domainClass.getName(), entityId);
    }
}
```

Now, the problem is that, when i run previous method calls, in the `saveAndGetDetailsCount`, hibernate does not execute `select...` query and logs **0** as comments count.

I wondered why this happened.

**UPDATE**

Maybe you ask why i didn't used from `EntityManager` insteadof `Session`, i have some limitation to use `EntityManager`.

**UPDATE**

When i call the `saveAndGetDetailsCount`, the `entity` parameter contains only `id` and `title` and in the next lines as you can see i want to load `comments` field and get it's size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is not in migration to hibernate 5 .I think your problem is in transaction.When persist or merge call in same transaction, loadById dose not execute until method return .You can flush after save to merge working correctly and your object load .

change your code to this

```
@Repository
public abstract class GenericRepository<T extends BaseEntity,PK extends Serializable> {

    protected Class<T> domainClass = getDomainClass();

    /* changed */
    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

    public Session getSession() {
        /* changed */
        return  em.unwrap(Session.class);
    }

    public PK save(T Entity) {
        Session session = getSession();
        if(entity.getId() == null) {
            em.persist(entity);
        }
        else {
            em.merge(entity);
            em.flush();
        }
        return entity.getId();
    }

    public T loadByEntityId(PK entityId) {
        Session session = getSession();
        return  (T) session.get(domainClass.getName(), entityId);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why should it generate a query if the entity is already attached to the current Session?

Also, Why do you call merge and the update? You should use either one or the other. But not both.

Comment: it's was my fault to call both of `merge` and `update`. please check my second update

Comment: If you merge it, the returned entity is managed so just traverse the child collection and you'll get it initialized.

Comment: I changed it to `entity = (T)session.merge(entity);`, but didn't worked again!

Comment: And did you access the association after merge?

Comment: no, it logged **0** again and it's means i cannot access association after merge.